# How to migrate from internal postgres db to external postgres db in gitlab

Tags: postgresql, migration, gitlab

Currently we have all in one single docker container for our production gitlab, where we are using bundled postgres and redis. So everything in same container. We want to use external postgres db and separate container for redis as well to follow the production standards.

How can I migrate from internal postgres db to external postgres db? If anyone provides process and steps that will be really helpful. We are new to this process. Please let us know If anyone knows

Thank you everyone for your inputs ,

PRS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can follow the article "[Migrating GitLab from internal to external PostgreSQL](https://noobient.com/2018/06/25/migrating-gitlab-from-internal-to-external/)", which involves:

- a database dump/reload, using [`pg_dumpall`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/backup-dump.html)

  ```
  sudo -u gitlab-psql /opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/pg_dumpall \
   --username=gitlab-psql --host=/var/opt/gitlab/postgresql > /var/lib/pgsql/database.sql
  sudo -u postgres psql -f /var/lib/pgsql/database.sql
  ```

Note: yuo can also use a backup of the database, but only if the external PostgreSQL version matches exactly the embedded one.

- setting its password

  ```
  sudo -u postgres psql -c "ALTER USER gitlab ENCRYPTED PASSWORD '***' VALID UNTIL 'infinity';"
  ```
- and modifying the GitLab configuration:

That is:

```
# Disable the built-in Postgres
postgresql['enable'] = false
# Fill in the connection details
gitlab_rails['db_adapter'] = 'postgresql'
gitlab_rails['db_encoding'] = 'utf8'
gitlab_rails['db_host'] = '127.0.0.1'
gitlab_rails['db_port'] = 5432
gitlab_rails['db_database'] = "gitlabhq_production"
gitlab_rails['db_username'] = 'gitlab'
gitlab_rails['db_password'] = '***'
```

- apply tour changes:

  ```
  gitlab-ctl reconfigure && gitlab-ctl restart
  ```

Comment: please see the answer I have given above...didn't have much space to comment and explain my process here .. Please look and let me know what do you think..Thanks

Comment: @Prs That seems basically the same as my answer. That should work.

Comment: @VonC..We haven't used pgdump databse export and import as explained in document. Instead we have used backup and restore gitlab commands with pointing to external db? Are they both considered same process?

Comment: @Prs Only if the PostgreSQL is *exactly* the same between the embedded one and the external one. If not, a dump/reload is safer.

Comment: we have created a new postgres container with exactly same version as in embedded one [bundled postgres ] .

Comment: Thank you for your inputs :)

Comment: @VonC, thanks so much! You saved my day :)

Answer (score 0):

@VonC

Hi, let me know about the process I have done below

We currently have single all in one docker gitlab container which is using bundled postgres and redis . To follow the production standards we are looking to maintain separate postgres and redis instances for our prod gitlab..We already have data in bundled db ..so we took back up current gitlab with bundled postgres ..it generated .tar file....Next we did change gitlab.rb to point external post gres db [ same version ]..then we are able connect to gitlab but didn;t see any data because nothing was there as it is fresh db.  Later we did the restore  using external postgres db ...now we can see all the data?? Can we do in this method ? Now our gitlab is attached to external postgres and I can see all the restored data. Will this process works ? Any downfalls?

How this process is different from pgdump and import ?